# Multiple conditions with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Using coffeescript, I want to be able to change my search icon to completely opaque when I hover over it. But only when the search input field is not in focus. When in focus, I don't wan't the hover to have any affect at all. So I have a custom class in css that I only want to trigger when both of these events are true. Something like:

```
 if $(".search input")is(":hover") && !$(".search input")is(":focus")  
  $(".regular-icon").addClass("iconhover")
```

where that custom .iconhover class in css would be

```
.iconhover {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me. Is there anyway to combine the conditions in a way where hovering over the search icon only makes it opaque when the input is not in focus?

The HTML page:

```
        <ul class="nav">
                <li><%= link_to "home" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "about" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "help" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "tags" %></li>
                <li class="searchbox">
                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                   <%= form_with(model: @something, class: "search") do |form| %>
                   <%= form.text_field :search %>
                   <% end %>

                  </div>
                    <a href="#"><i class="regular-icon"></i><a>
                <li>
        </ul>
```

my coffeescript:

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  $(document).scroll ->
    scroll_start = 0
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop()
    if scroll_start > 575
      $(".main").addClass("change")
    else
      $(".main").removeClass("change")

  if $(".search input")is(":hover") && !$(".search input")is(":focus")  
    $(".regular-icon").addClass("iconhover")
```

and the related css is:

```
.iconhover {
 opacity: 1;
}   //which is the class I want to change to

.regular-icon {
color: black;
opacity: 0.4;
 }  //the current styling of the icon
```

Comment: `.search input` is not the same as `search.input`. Did you mean to use different selectors there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do Coffeescript, so my answer is in plain Javascript, you'll have to translate it.

To run code when the user hovers over an element, use the `.hover()` method.

You'll also need a `.focus()` handler, so you remove the class when the user focuses on the input, since `.hover()` only runs when the user enters or leaves, not when state changes while they're already hovered.

```js
$(".search input").hover(function() {
    $(".regular-icon").toggleClass("iconhover", !$(this).is(":focus"));
  },
  function() {
    $(".regular-icon").removeClass("iconhover");
  }).focus(function() {
  $(".regular-icon").removeClass("iconhover")
});
```

```css
.regular-icon.iconhover {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input>
</div>
<div class="regular-icon">Icon</div>
```

Comment: Tested it out. It doesn't seem to execute. The  new iconhover class doesn't have any affect. Tested on multiple browsers. Still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Can you post the HTML? The code in the question seems to have lots of typos that make it hard to tell what the correct selector should be.

Comment: Updated what the HTML looks like .

Comment: How are you running this `if` statement? Can you create an MCVE?

Comment: Yes. My entire script is very small just a scroll function and the function we're working on now. I updated with the full coffeescript and the related css. And that's just about everything related to the issue.

Comment: It's `addClass`, not `addclass`. And you never remove the class.

Comment: Typo in the question. The code is `addClass`  but it still doesn't work. And planning to add removeClass functionality later. But I just wan't to get it working for now. Perhaps this isn't a valid statement in jquery?

Comment: Is this test supposed to be inside the `scroll` handler? If you're scolling the page, how can you also be hovering over an input?

Comment: And if it's not inside the scroll handler, it will only run when the page is first loaded, not when the user hovers over the input field.

Comment: It is not intended to be a part of the scroll function, and oh I see. I tried putting the if statement on the top level and it still would not execute, so I figured all functions had to be apart of that `.on "page:load"` handler. Any suggestions on how to fix that  so that it executes whenever the user hovers?

Comment: Use `$(selector).hover(func1, func2)`. `func1` runs when the user enters the element, `func2` runs when they leave it.

Comment: can you update your answer with an example that includes `not:focus` functionality?

Comment: I'm trying to get it working. But your question is confusing, probably another typo. "But only when the search input field is not in focus. When out of focus I don't wan't the hover to have any affect at all." Isn't "not in focus" the same as "out of focus"?

Comment: What are you hovering over, the input field or the search icon?

Comment: I'm hovering over the input field, and adding a change class function on the search icon... based on the condition that the input field is out of focus.

Comment: Meant to say that I only wan't the affect when the input field is out of focus. When in focus, I don't want any affect at all

Comment: Question says "change my search icon to completely opaque when I hover over it."

Comment: Yes, when out of focus, I would like the .iconhover class to take effect. When the input field is not in focus, and I hover over that same input field, I would like the search icon to turn completely opaque. Else, the regular-icon css.

Comment: In that sentence, "it" is the search icon, not the input field.

Comment: it referring to the input field, the input field hovering is what everything is based on. I'm not trying to achieve any effect hovering over the search icon alone, just the input field.

Comment: So again to be clear, when the input field is out of focus...and I hover over the input field.... I want the iconhover class for my search icon instead of the regular-icon class.

Comment: And when the input field is IN focus and I hover over it, nothing should happen at all.

Comment: I understand now what you want, but it's not what the question says. It says **change my search icon to completely opaque when I hover over it.** It should say "when I hover over the input field"

Comment: Anyway, see the answer. The main thing you're missing is that you have to do everything in event handlers, so the code runs when the user does something.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for taking the time to help.